# No sound trying to play a Python sound on Raspberry Pi

Tags: audio

Just wondering if anyone can help me get sound to work on a Raspberry Pi?

I keep getting an error message:

`my_sound = pygame.mixer.my_sound('/home/pi/gpio-music-box/samples/drum_tom_mid_hard.wav') AttributeError: module 'pygame.mixer' has no attribute 'my_sound'`

Is there something wrong in the code or my setup?
My code is below!

Thanks

```
import pygame

pygame.init

Sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('/home/pi/gpio-music-box/samples/drum_tom_mid_hard.wav')

Sound.play()
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your code is as shown? The error message suggests that you’ve used “.my_sound(...)” rather than “.sound(...)”.  The code as written would not give that error message.

Looking at [the API documentation for pygame.mixer](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html), it looks like it should be “.Sound(...)” with a capital “S”. It’s a constructor, so that makes sense.

Comment: sorry my mistake!

Comment: It still gives AttributeError: module 'pygame.mixer' has no attribute 'sound' after changing it to sound rather than my_sound

Comment: @Dave See my edit.

Comment: It's now giving me this error unable to open file '/home/pi/gpio-music-box/samples/drum_tom_mid_hard.wav' but the capital S seems to have resolved the other issue thanks

Comment: why is it not opening the file? is my path correct for it?

Comment: Who knows? Only you can tell what files you have available, and at what locations.

Comment: the file location is correct and available why I'm asking is I have checked it 100% and I can play the sound file too, as a Flac as well as a Wav but the python says unable to open so I was wondering if it's finding the correct path?

Comment: could it be anything relating to the os version I have?

Comment: Could I not use a different method to have a sound play?

Comment: I’m sorry, at this point you need somebody who has used this particular API, perhaps in this environment, and I haven’t. You’d have way better luck asking this on the programmer’s site  stackoverflow.com rather than here.

Comment: @Dave *"It's now giving me this error unable to open file '/home/pi/gpio-music-box/samples/drum_tom_mid_hard.wav'"* -- The most likely culprits are either a simple path parsing issue or a permission issue. There is some small chance it could be an issue with the file itself, but you won't know unless you attempt to play other files. But OP is correct, you will want to ask a new question regarding this issue if you need help, whether here on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or on e.g. [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @Dave It's also probably worth mentioning that there is a [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) as well.